# Which Active Directory tenant type to use for Auth0 social login?

Tags: azure-active-directory, auth0

We have a public consumer application for which we use Auth0 as identity platform and through Auth0 we have enabled a couple of social logins to which we now want to add "Login with Microsoft" as an option so that anyone with any type of Microsoft account can login.

Obviously we will need to enable the Microsoft social connection in our Auth0 instance and connect it to a Active Directory Application and Tenant created in Azure.

What I can't seem to find the answer for is which type of tenant we should setup for this, whether we should use a *Azure Active Directory* tenant with a multi-tenant application or if we should use a *Azure Active Directory (B2C)* tenant for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gathered the following insights since posting my question

**Summary**

- Auth0 Social connection -> Azure Active Directory tenant with an app configured to support "Personal Microsoft accounts"
- Auth0 Enterprise connection -> Azure Active Directory tenant with an app configured to support "Accounts in any organisational directory and personal Microsoft accounts"

See guide of different app types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application)

**Details**

- Since we wanted to support login with any microsoft account (multi tenant + personal) my initial attempt of using an Auth0 Social connection for this was incorrect, since the Social connection will only allow successful logins with personal accounts regardless of how you have setup the App registration in Azure
- Auth0 Enterprise connection is the way to go for our case, with an Azure app registation supporting multi tenant + personal accounts. Also when setting the connection up in Auth0, make sure to enable the "Use common endpoint" setting as described [here](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/identity-providers/enterprise-identity-providers/azure-active-directory/v2#create-an-enterprise-connection-in-auth0)
- The Azure Active Directory B2C tenant type is not useful with any of the Auth0 connections as you likely won't be able to get a satisfying consent screen with verified publisher. I'm guessing its just the wrong way of using the B2C tenant, where its supposed to be used the other way around with the Azure tenant being the identity platform optionally integrating applications from Auth0 like in [the answer from Mavric20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74037731/5659411)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting your query. As per https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/identity-providers/enterprise-identity-providers/azure-active-directory/v2#register-your-app-with-azure-ad Azure AD would support for multitenant apps but not with social account (until you plan to send invitation to each user's personal account for Azure AD B2B).

[image: Account Types]

For Microsoft Social accounts Azure B2C would suit your requirement.

**On Auth0 Admin Console:**

Create a web application in Auth0

Copy the client ID and secret

Add a callback URL from your B2C tenant in given format: https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

Copy the “OpenID Configuration” URI from advance setting.

**On Azure B2C tenant:**

Add an Identity provider to B2C, Azure AD B2C > Identity providers > New OpenID Connect Provider

Input “OpenID Configuration” URI you copied in above step to Metadata URL.

Similarly add client ID and Client secret you copied from Auth0.

Complete the claims mapping ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-user-flow#claims-mapping

Hit Save and Auth0 will be saved as IDP in your Azure B2C tenant.

Thanks